# How to consolidate the task list instead of multiple task lists?

Tags: sharepoint-online, task-list

I have multiple task lists using in different workflows and subsites. I want to consolidate all task lists using single task list instead of multiple task list.
how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to show all the tasks in multiple site into a single task list.

Here are my suggestions :

1. Create a publishing page layout.
2. Insert the content query web part
3. Customize the query.

In this way you can display all the tasks in a single web part ,but you cannot connect this web part to Outlook .You have to manually connect task items to outlook one by one .

**There is another workaround**

You can create a task list to save all the task items .And create an event handler to copy the task items to this new task list when the user creates\update the item. Then you can connect the new task list to outlook .

For more detailed information, please refer to this site:

[Display data from multiple lists with the Content Query Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-content-query-web-part-HA010174134.aspx)

[Event handler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianwilson/archive/tags/event+handlers/)

Comment: Did you tried above solution? Is that works for for you?